# Relation from one table to another with two columns in the primary key in SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server, foreign-keys, primary-key

I am trying to make a relation from a table to another like the following :

**Books**

```
IdBook (primary)
SerialNumber (primary)
NameBook
```

The other table is :

**Qtt**

```
IdQtt (primary)
IdBook
Qtt
```

How can I make a relation **only** between `Qtt.IdBook` and `Books.IdBook` ?

Comment: If you have a compound primary key (made up from multiple columns), then **all** foreign keys referencing that table **must also** include **all** those columns - no exceptions. You **cannot** reference only half a PK - it's an all or nothing deal

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You meant to create a `FOREIGN KEY` relationship between the tables on that column like

```
CONSTRAINT FK_idbook FOREIGN KEY (IdBook)     
    REFERENCES Books (IdBook)     
    ON DELETE CASCADE    
    ON UPDATE CASCADE
```

But that will not work since you have composite PK in your `Books` table on `IdBook, SerialNumber` and thus you need another key column in your `Qtt` table to refer to both PK column else it would be a PFD (partial functional dependency)

```
constraint FK_book FOREIGN KEY (IdBook,IdQtt) references Books (IdBook,SerialNumber)
```

Answer (score 0):

Although it is technically possible to create a `UNIQUE` constraint on `Books.IdBook` and a `FOREIGN KEY` constraint on `Qtt.Book` referencing that column, this probably won't work with your data model because `IdBook` alone doesn't uniquely identify a `Books` row. You need a table like `BookTitle` keyed by IdBook, with a one-to-many relationship to Books and another one-to-many relationship from `BookTitle` to Qtt on `IdBook`.